# Get field and nested field at the same time using jq

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to get two attributes I need from the JIRA API. Given the following input to JQ:

```
{
  "expand": "names,schema",
  "startAt": 0,
  "maxResults": 50,
  "total": 1,
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields",
      "id": "73270",
      "key": "RM-111",
      "fields": {
        "statuscategorychangedate": "2020-09-29T15:12:18.837+0100",
        "lastViewed": "2020-09-30T09:25:38.846+0100",
        "summary": "6.6.0"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get the following output:

`RM-111 6.6.0`

I can get them individually:

```
> cat rm111.json | jq -r '.issues[] | .key'
RM-111

> cat rm111.json | jq -r '.issues[] | .fields.summary'
6.6.0
```

I can get them separated by new lines:

```
> cat rm111.json | jq -r '.issues[] | .key,.fields.summary'
RM-111
6.6.0
```

But the following (which should give the format I actually need) does not work and I cannot figure out why:

```
> cat rm111.json | jq -r '.issues[] | .key .fields.summary'
jq: error (at <stdin>:18): Cannot index string with string "fields"
```

I need to iterate over issues[] because there may be more than the one shown in this example.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As a list of tab-separated values: Create an array of the wanted values for each `issue[]` and pass it to `@tsv`.

```
$ jq -r '.issues[] | [ .key, .fields.summary ] | @tsv' file.json
RM-111  6.6.0
```

As a string with the two values separated by a space: Create a double quoted string for each `issue[]` and use `\(...)` to interpolate the values within the string.

```
$ jq -r '.issues[] | "\(.key) \(.fields.summary)"' file.json
RM-111 6.6.0
```

---

The issue with the last two of your commands are that the first of them first gets `.key` and then `.fields.summary`.  These two pieces of data would be outputted on separate lines.

The last command tries to extract `.key.fields.summary`, which does not exist.